# Solving Simultaneous Equations with 6 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have been given the following information;

$$a+b=15150$$
$$x+y=101$$
$$\frac{a}{x}=i_1$$
$$\frac{a-124}{x-1}=i_1+\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{b}{y}=i_2$$
$$\frac{b+124}{y+1}=i_2+\frac{1}{3}$$

I have to find any possible integer solutions for $a,b,x,y$.

So far I have rearranged the equations and tried to eliminate variables but can't seem to get any closer to a working solution. Would welcome some suggestions.

Comment: This looks like six variables to me.

Comment: Are $i_1$ and $i_2$ variables or pre-defined constants?

Comment: You could solve as a linear system in $a, b, x, y$ with $i_1$ and $i_2$ as parameters.

Comment: Yes $i_1$ and $i_2$ are variables, I forgot about them as wasn't asked to actually find them.

Comment: I think you could substitute $i_1 = \frac ax$ into $\frac{a-124}{x-1}=i_1+\frac{1}{3}$ and $i_2 = \frac by$ into \frac{b+124}{y+1}=i_2+\frac{1}{3} to find some possible values and then cross check by substituting the values into $a + b = 15150$ and $x + y = 101$.

Comment: The solution is unique $$a = 13830,b = 1320,x = 90,y = 11$$ With $$i_1 = \frac{461}{3},i_2= 120$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b=15150 \\
 x+y=101 \\
 \dfrac{a}{x}=i_1  \\
 \dfrac{a-124}{x-1}=i_1+\dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{b}{y}=i_2  \\
 \dfrac{b+124}{y+1}=i_2+\dfrac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right.$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b=15150 \\
 x+y=101 \\
 \dfrac{a}{x}=i_1  \\
 \dfrac{a-124}{x-1}=\dfrac{a}{x}+\dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{b}{y}=i_2  \\
 \dfrac{b+124}{y+1}=\dfrac{b}{y}+\dfrac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right.$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b=15150 \\
 x+y=101 \\
 \dfrac{a}{x}=i_1  \\
\dfrac{b}{y}=i_2  \\
\dfrac{3 a-x^2-371 x}{3 (x-1) x}=0\to 3 a-x^2-371 x=0\\
\dfrac{-3 b-y^2+371 y}{3 y (y+1)}=0\to -3 b-y^2+371 y=0\\
\end{array}
\right.$

Subtract the last two equations

$$3 a-x^2-371 x-\left(-3 b-y^2+371 y\right)=0\to 3 a-x^2-371 x+3b+y^2-371y=0$$

$$3(a+b)-371(x+y)-(x+y)(x-y)=0\to x-y=79$$

$$3\times 15150-371\times 101-101(x-y)=0$$
$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b=15150 \\
 x+y=101 \\
 x-y=79 \\
\end{array}
\right.$

Add second and third equation to get $2x=180\to x=90$

and $y=101-90=11$

Plug back in the original system

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b=15150 \\
 \dfrac{a}{90}=i_1  \\
\dfrac{b}{11}=i_2 \to b=11i_2 \\
 \dfrac{b+124}{12}=i_2+\dfrac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right.$

Plug the third into the fourth

$\dfrac{11i_2+124}{12}=i_2+\dfrac{1}{3}\to i_2=120$

$b=1320$

And finally $a=15150-1320=13830$

Hope this helps

Comment: Just came online to literally post something similar as the answer after some clues from other people. Thanks for doing it for me :) bit slow at typing maths in this form.

Answer (score 1):

substituting eqn3 in eqn4, we get
$$\frac{a-124}{x-1}=\frac{a}{x}+\frac{1}{3}$$
analogously we get
$$\frac{b+124}{y+1}=\frac{b}{y}+\frac{1}{3}$$
using $$x=101-y,b=15150-a$$ we obtain
$$\frac{a-124}{100-y}=\frac{a}{101-y}+\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{15150-a+124}{y+1}=\frac{15150-a}{y}+\frac{1}{3}$$
plugging 
$$a=\frac{1}{3}(y-472)(y-101)$$ in our last equation and simplifying we get
$$-\frac{202 (y-11)}{3 y (y+1)}=0$$
this is a good starting Point to calculate the other variables, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another path to the solution

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rcll}a+b&=&15150&\quad  \left(1\right)\\
x+y&=&101&\quad  \left(2\right)\\
a-{i}_{1} x&=&0&\quad  \left(3\right)\\
b-{i}_{2} y&=&0&\quad  \left(4\right)\\
\displaystyle  a-\left({i}_{1}+\frac{1}{3}\right) x&=&\displaystyle -{i}_{1}+\frac{371}{3}&\quad  \left(5\right)\\
\displaystyle  b-\left({i}_{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right) y&=&\displaystyle  {i}_{2}-\frac{371}{3}&\quad  \left(6\right)
\end{array}$$

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  \begin{array}{rcll}x&=&3 {i}_{1}-371&\quad  \left(7\right) \Leftarrow  \left(3\right) , \left(5\right)\\
y&=&{-3} {i}_{2}+371&\quad  \left(8\right) \Leftarrow  \left(4\right) , \left(6\right)\\
3 \left({i}_{1}-{i}_{2}\right)&=&101&\left(9\right) \Leftarrow  \left(7\right) , \left(8\right) , \left(2\right)\\
a&=&3 {i}_{1}^{2}-371 {i}_{1}&\left(10\right) \Leftarrow  \left(3\right) , \left(7\right)\\
b&=&{-3} {i}_{2}^{2}+371 {i}_{2}&\left(11\right) \Leftarrow  \left(4\right) , \left(8\right)\\
\displaystyle  3 \left({i}_{1}-{i}_{2}\right) \left({i}_{1}+{i}_{2}-\frac{371}{3}\right)&=&15150&\left(12\right) \Leftarrow  \left(1\right) , \left(10\right) , \left(11\right)\\
{i}_{1}+{i}_{2}&=&\displaystyle  \frac{821}{3}&\left(13\right) \Leftarrow  \left(9\right) , \left(12\right)\\
{i}_{1}&=&\displaystyle  \frac{461}{3}&\left(14\right) \Leftarrow  \left(9\right) , \left(13\right)\\
{i}_{2}&=&\displaystyle  120&\left(15\right) \Leftarrow  \left(9\right) , \left(13\right)\\
x&=&90&\left(16\right) \Leftarrow  \left(14\right) , \left(7\right)\\
y&=&11&\left(17\right) \Leftarrow  \left(14\right) , \left(8\right)\\
a&=&13830&\left(18\right) \Leftarrow  \left(16\right) ,(14), \left(3\right)\\
b&=&1320&\left(19\right) \Leftarrow  \left(17\right) , (15),\left(4\right)
\end{array}$$